# Unexpected keyword argument "context" when using appcfg.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I tried to update a project on Google App Engine via appcfg.py:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" update c:\secondApp
```

But I get the following error immediately (top lines are ignored):

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
TypeError: do_open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

I decided to dig into the file `urllib2.py` and find the problem. After a few minutes of code reviewing, I came to this conclusion that an overload accepting a parameter named `context` does not exist. So, I changed the original code snippet:

```
def https_open(self, req):
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req,
        context=self._context)
```

to

```
def https_open(self, req):
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
```

and Voila! It works (although another problem regarding authentication arise, but the first problem get solved). But it is very strange that in an official release there exists a bug like this while is very likely other people have encountered the same problem. Surprisingly, I couldn't find this issue reported by anyone else!

Is there anything wrong in the module? Am I mixing wrong versions of installed packages? Any help?

My Google App Engine SDK Version: 1.9.17 x64

My Installed Python Version: 2.7.9 x64

My Platform: Windows 8.1 x64

and I am not familiar with Python :D

**Solution:**

As Migel Tissera mentioned the problem is about authentication. But I tried his proposed command and got the same error. Fortunately, I executed the following command and success! (I added --noauth_local_webserver and --no_cookies switches too):

```
appcfg.py --noauth_local_webserver --oauth2 --skip_sdk_update_check --no_cookies update c:\secondApp
```

Comment: This could also be a bug with [GAE on 2.7.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453497)

Comment: Do you have 2-Step Verification turned on for this Google account?

Comment: @whiteshooz No I don't

Comment: The workaround at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11536 worked for me. Just had to change three lines of code and Voila! My GAE/P is up now!

Comment: Seems to be fixed in the current SDK release, 1.9.18 -- can you please check that upgrading the SDK does make this problem goes away?  Sorry it took us a while to address this but I think/hope it's fixed now...!  Thanks for the heads-up BTW:-)

Answer (score 27):

I ran in to the same problem about half an hour ago.. It's actually nothing to do with the urllib2 file, it's got something to do with the authentication. This fixed it for me..

Use **appcfg.py** with **--oauth2** flag. Try this, **appcfg.py --oauth2 update /path/to/your/app**. In the first time you will see the browser window where you'll need to allow access to your account. Then you can deploy your app without entering email and password.

I hope this helps. Glad to post my first answer here! :)

Thanks,
Migel

Comment: Do you know how to make the remote api client accept OAuth2? At the moment, invoking the remote shell gives the same error (i.e. $GAE_SDK_ROOT/remote_api_shell.py -s <app-id>.appspot.com), unfortunately.)

Comment: Your answer is great, but not working in my case. See the update. I upvote.

Answer (score -1):

This error might also occur when using an incompatible version of the Appengine SDK.

In my case upgrading the SDK fixed it.