# Google App Engine Launcher is not working

Tags: google-app-engine

I have successfully installed google app engine SDK for python and google app engine launcher.I also added prefrence path in launcher.I create an app name 'engineapp' by google app engine launcher. I specify port 8080 on localhost to run this app but it is not working.There is a message shown in Log Console of app launcher which is given here

```
2015-07-21 07:23:53 PM Running command: "['/usr/bin/python', '/home/rishi/Downloads/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8080', u'/home/rishi/prcts/engineapp']"
usage: dev_appserver.py [-h] [-A APP_ID] [--host HOST] [--port PORT]
                        [--admin_host ADMIN_HOST] [--admin_port ADMIN_PORT]
                        [--auth_domain AUTH_DOMAIN] [--storage_path PATH]
                        [--log_level {debug,info,warning,critical,error}]
                        [--max_module_instances MAX_MODULE_INSTANCES]
                        [--use_mtime_file_watcher [USE_MTIME_FILE_WATCHER]]
                        [--threadsafe_override THREADSAFE_OVERRIDE]
                        [--php_executable_path PATH]
                        [--php_remote_debugging [PHP_REMOTE_DEBUGGING]]
                        [--php_gae_extension_path PATH]
                        [--php_xdebug_extension_path PATH]
                        [--appidentity_email_address APPIDENTITY_EMAIL_ADDRESS]
                        [--appidentity_private_key_path APPIDENTITY_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH]
                        [--python_startup_script PYTHON_STARTUP_SCRIPT]
                        [--python_startup_args PYTHON_STARTUP_ARGS]
                        [--jvm_flag JVM_FLAG]
                        [--custom_entrypoint CUSTOM_ENTRYPOINT]
                        [--blobstore_path BLOBSTORE_PATH]
                        [--mysql_host MYSQL_HOST] [--mysql_port MYSQL_PORT]
                        [--mysql_user MYSQL_USER]
                        [--mysql_password MYSQL_PASSWORD]
                        [--mysql_socket MYSQL_SOCKET]
                        [--datastore_path DATASTORE_PATH]
                        [--clear_datastore [CLEAR_DATASTORE]]
                        [--datastore_consistency_policy {consistent,random,time}]
                        [--require_indexes [REQUIRE_INDEXES]]
                        [--auto_id_policy {sequential,scattered}]
                        [--logs_path LOGS_PATH]
                        [--show_mail_body [SHOW_MAIL_BODY]]
                        [--enable_sendmail [ENABLE_SENDMAIL]]
                        [--smtp_host SMTP_HOST] [--smtp_port SMTP_PORT]
                        [--smtp_user SMTP_USER]
                        [--smtp_password SMTP_PASSWORD]
                        [--smtp_allow_tls [SMTP_ALLOW_TLS]]
                        [--prospective_search_path PROSPECTIVE_SEARCH_PATH]
                        [--clear_prospective_search [CLEAR_PROSPECTIVE_SEARCH]]
                        [--search_indexes_path SEARCH_INDEXES_PATH]
                        [--clear_search_indexes [CLEAR_SEARCH_INDEXES]]
                        [--enable_task_running [ENABLE_TASK_RUNNING]]
                        [--allow_skipped_files [ALLOW_SKIPPED_FILES]]
                        [--api_port API_PORT]
                        [--automatic_restart [AUTOMATIC_RESTART]]
                        [--dev_appserver_log_level {debug,info,warning,critical,error}]
                        [--skip_sdk_update_check [SKIP_SDK_UPDATE_CHECK]]
                        [--default_gcs_bucket_name DEFAULT_GCS_BUCKET_NAME]
                        yaml_path [yaml_path ...]
dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --admin_console_server=
2015-07-21 07:23:53 PM (Process exited with code 2)
```

I didn't know what's going wrong here.can someone help me to fix this error?

Comment: It tells you what's wrong. `dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --admin_console_server=`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error running google app engine: unrecognized arguments: admin\_console\_server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414207/error-running-google-app-engine-unrecognized-arguments-admin-console-server)

Comment: Thanks Popnodles, It solve the problem.Everything is working fine now.